# Large biconnected component in expander with edges removed?

Tags: graph-theory

I believe the following statement about expanders is true and very likely known; does anyone have a simple proof or a reference?

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an $n$-node bounded-degree expander (say degree 3).  Let $S \subset E$ be a set of edges, and let $G - S$ denote the graph $(V,E\setminus S).$  Then the number of bridges in $G - S$ is $O(|S|)$.

(Equivalently, $G-S$ has a biconnected component of size $n - O(|S|)$, where we say that a component is biconnected if removing any single edge does not disconnect it, i.e. every vertex lies on a cycle).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess Lemma 1 in Section 8.5.1 here says that its true if you don't demand biconnected. Maybe then you could show that the connected component must also have a well connected subgraph (I don't know much about expanders. Also I can't comment yet)

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mmahoney/s15-stat260-cs294/Lectures/lecture08-17feb15.pdf